# Run two functions parallel in While True Loop

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have made a Cookie Clicker game on Python and am trying to get two functions to run in parallel while in an infinite loop.

I need them to be in parallel, since I want one of them to add one to a variable every second and the other one to add one to another variable every ten seconds. I do this by just using `time.sleep()`, but if I use the same loop for both, it's just gonna run the first function, wait 1s then add one and then wait 10s and add another one.

Does anyone know a way around this?

```
def farm():
   time.sleep(random.choice(range(1, 3)))`
   x += 1

def automatic():
   time.sleep(random.choice(range(1, 10)))
   y += 1

while True:
   farm()
   automatic()
```

*This is my code kinda simplified*

I tried using two different threads from the threading library, but that started crashing.

Comment: What have you tried? In your simplified code you are not using any threading. Atm you don't show enough research effort.
Also: Try to keep your code runable

Comment: Conceptually, this isn't idea. Games are typically controlled via a game loop. In each "loop run" it gets decided what to do. See https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/gamedev-glossary-what-is-the-game-loop--gamedev-2469 for example or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301193/whats-the-proper-way-to-write-a-game-loop-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using threading, you can move your sleep outside of each function and check in each cycle if relevant function should trigger.

```
import time, random

def farm():
    print("farm")

def automatic():
    print("automatic")

next_farm = random.choice(range(1, 3))
next_automatic = random.choice(range(1, 10))
    
while True:
    if next_farm > 0:
        next_farm -= 1
    else:
        farm()
        next_farm = random.choice(range(1, 3))

    if next_automatic > 0:
        next_automatic -= 1
    else:
        automatic()
        next_automatic = random.choice(range(1, 10))

    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what framework you're using to make the game. I'm assuming you're using PyGame (because of the infinite loop), which is incompatible with multithreading. I recommend you keep track of the last event trigger, such as when `automatic` and `farm` were called using the `time` or `datetime` modules, and call them when e.g. 1s or 10s has elapsed by checking with an if statement.

Comment: I use TigerJython, as I am making this for school.
Thank you for your answer I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run both functions in parallel you can do this:

```
from threading import Thread

def func1():
    print('Working')

def func2():
    print("Working")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = func1).start()
    Thread(target = func2).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with threads will fix your problem:

```
def farm():
    x = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(random.choice(range(1, 3))) 
        x += 1
        print('Thread 1 value is: '+str(x))

def automatic():
    y = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(random.choice(range(1, 10))) 
        y += 1
        print('Thread 2 value is: '+str(y))

e = threading.Event()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=farm)
t1.start()
t2 = threading.Thread(target=automatic)
t2.start()
```